# Python operator filter dosen't work (Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, if-statement, instagram

Hey guys I am trying to filtered a few instagram users with selenium & python, the goal is to following all user have more following than followers but i don't know why he return me same result:

For exemple for this account :

[image]

Normaly it he must to print me "have more followers than following"

My code :

```py
followers = []    #list of url users
for follower in followers:
    #Iterate into the list
    scrap_follower = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[2]/a/span').get_attribute("title")
    
    scrap_following = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[3]/a/span').text
    
    
    follower_count = int(scrap_follower)
    following_count = int(scrap_following)
    
    browser.get(follower)
    sleep(2)
    
    followButton = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('button')
    
    print(follower_count)
    print(following_count)     
    
    if follower_count == 0:
        pass
        print("0 followers")
        
        if follower_count > following_count :
            print("have more followers than following")
            pass
    else:
        print("eligible")
            #Go to follow
```

my console log return:

[image]

Thanks for your Help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second `if` statement needs to align with the first one otherwise it will never execute unless the `if follower_count == 0:` condition is met.

Your code:

```
follower_count = 1500
following_count = 1000

print(follower_count)
print(following_count)     

if follower_count == 0:
    pass
    print("0 followers")
    
    if follower_count > following_count :
        print("have more followers than following")
        pass
else:
    print("eligible")
```

Results (incorrect):

```
1500
1000
eligible
```

Correct code (2nd `if` statement aligned with first `if` statement)

```
follower_count = 1500
following_count = 1000

print(follower_count)
print(following_count)     

if follower_count == 0:
    pass
    print("0 followers")
    
if follower_count > following_count :
    print("have more followers than following")
    pass
else:
    print("eligible")
```

Results:

```
1500
1000
have more followers than following
```

Comment: Ah i'm dumb it working for me now, Thank you so much :)

Comment: If it's working, accept/upvote the answer. It is how SO works.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you pasted with wrong indentation, but the logic in your code seems little wrong.

```
if follower_count == 0:
    pass
    print("0 followers")
        
    if follower_count > following_count :
        print("have more followers than following")
        pass
else:
    print("eligible")
    #Go to follow
```

Changing this to something like below may help:

```
if follower_count == 0:
    print("0 followers")
else:
    if follower_count > following_count :
        print("have more followers than following")
    else:
        print("eligible")
```

And `pass` statement is just a null statement, you can use `continue` or `break` to control the loop. But for code as above as those are the last statements in loop and also with conditionals, you won't need those control statements as of now.

Comment: Yeah is working too, thanks so much bro ;)